# Force browser to use woff font file

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, woff

I have defined following `@font-face` rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url(MyFont.eot);
    src: url(MyFont.eot#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(MyFont.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(MyFont.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Since there were some bug in the `woff` font file I have fixed it and I need to test if font looks correct right now.

The problem is that i.e. Google Chrome uses `ttf` by default and I cannot modify the `@font-face` in the runtime - also I cannot modify the CSS on the server because of the complicated pipeline.

Can we force somehow the browser to use specific font file type ?

Comment: No unfortunately not. But you could add the font to a converter to output the correct web font formats. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator , but seeing as you can't edit the CSS i suppose you have no way of using your font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test the woff file is working now, you can:

1. Try Firefox, I believe they prioritise WOFF, or
2. Temporarily change your `@font-face` code so Google Chrome only has WOFF as an option:

```
font-family: "MyFont";
src: url(MyFont.woff) format('woff');
```